# How to Highlight an excel row based on the results of a dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using Excel 2016.  I have an excel spreadsheet (sheet A) that has a cell with a dropdown that contains numbers.  Values are 50.01 through 75.99.  I have a second sheet (sheet B) that has a corresponding row for each of the values in the drop down.  I would like to change the fill color for the full row in sheet B if the number matches the drop down selection in sheet A.

For example I select the value 66.09 in the drop down on sheet A, the row representing 66.09 in sheet B should be changed to the new fill color.  if the drop down in sheet A changes to 74.66, the fill color in sheet B for value 66.09 should revert to normal and the row representing 74.66 should be filled with the fill color.

I know you can do this with conditional rules but I don't want to create a rule for the 2500+ entries.  Any thoughts on the best way to do this?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How have you created the drop down? Is it an 'activeX' control for example?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Chad Portman works, but I did stumble upon a few things trying to get it to work, so I'll clarify his steps a bit more.

I assume you made the dropdown list by using data validation using a "list" which references your data in Sheet2 correct? ("validation box")

If so you can achieve your row highlighting by going to Sheet2, pressing ctrl+a to select all, then adding a new conditional formatting rule. You will use the "Format only cells that contain" rule type. @Chad Portman recommended using:

```
=$A1=Sheet1!$B$1
```

Note, your validation box must be located on Sheet1 in cell B1 by this reference. If you validation box is elsewhere, change this reference.

This code also assumes that all of your values 50.01 through 75.99 are located in column A in sheet2. If they are in a different column, change the reference.

Note the $ signs (absolute cell/column references) are of vital importance here. Without them as they are, you will get all sorts of different conditional formatting results. 
    =$A1=Sheet1!$B$1

Comment: @topher217 Thank you for adding a little more detail to the steps. Glad to hear it solved your problem. Also AngusMudpaw, If the answer solved your issue you should check it as the answer. If you want you can add an upvote to either or both answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I made the assumption that your drop down list was a validation box. In my test spreadsheet the I made a validation box in Cell B1 on Sheet 1. Then on Sheet 2 I had my list of values and sample data with the values from the list in Col A.

I applied conditional formatting to the whole sheet using this formula:

```
=$A1=Sheet1!$B$1
```

Now anytime I adjust the validation box the second sheet updates which ones are highlighted. It will highlight every row that matches.